# Notification when my answer is viewed

Tags: support, answers, notifications

Is there anyway to know whether OP has viewed the answer that I have posted for his question? I feel like(pls correct me if I am wrong) answers go unnoticed, i.e without any comment, upvote/downvote.

I appreciate if my answer is downvoted with comment to improve incorrect/not useful answer, so that I know it has been viewed. I can now choose to improve or delete the answer. Is there any way currently to know this otherwise?

Reason for asking is some of the questions on SO contain many 0 vote answers. These answers may not be wrong as they dont have downvotes or comments. Would it be feasible to have a feature like this, if not present currently?

Thanks..

Comment: In short: no. Even if the user *viewed* the answer it does not mean he has actually *read* it. Only he knows that. Such feature isn't possible until every user will have special implant transmitting to Stack Exchange, and I doubt many people will agree to have it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd just make it a [USB Drive](http://xkcd.com/644/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP gets a notification every time there is an answer in his question, as well as a comment.

What he/she does not get is a notification if there is a comment in one of the answers.

You cannot know if the OP has read your answer, but you at least can check the "last seen" line in his/her profile.

Comment: That way you know when he has last visited the site and not the particular answer that I have posted.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It works as a negative: If he hasn't logger recently, then you know for sure that he has not seen your answer.

Comment: ...unless they read it using a browser that was not logged in ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Or had someone else browse to it and read it to them. Or read it in the Google search excerpt. Or hacked into the SE database and read it directly from the table. ;)

Comment: [No hacking required](http://api.stackexchange.com/), @George.